# jQuery Autocomplete - Display list of values on focus

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using [Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for a small set of values.  I would like the "Autocomplete" source values to immediately display when the user focuses on a the input box (either using the keyboard or mouse), rather than waiting for them to type.

How can I get the source values to immediately display upon focus?

Thank You,

```
        $("#cityInput").autocomplete({
            minLength: 0, // With not that many cities, require at no characters before showing autocomplete
            source: getJson(),
            // plug-in to the select event in order to keep KnockOut informed about the 
        });
```

Comment: "Right when the user focuses on the input box" I want to display the autocomplete list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by calling "search" method of autocomplete on its "focus" event, check this [JQFAQ.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-display-autocomplete-menu-on-focus-with-all-items/) topic which says how to do this. There are few other interesting FAQ related to autocomplecte, that may be helpful to you.