# jQuery Autocomplete - Display list of values on focus in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Previously I had asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574849/jquery-autocomplete-display-list-of-values-on-focus) and accepted the answer because it worked in Chrome.  This answer, however, does NOT work in IE 8 or IE 9 (and probably earlier versions as well).  What I mean by "doesn't work" is that in IE when selecting a value from the list, the menu should close, but it remains open.  I assume this is because the input keeps its focus when selecting a value.  How can I fix it in IE?

I created a [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GxsEC/4/) to illustrate this (open it in IE).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cityInput").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
    }).focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try returning `false` from the event handler:

```
$("#cityInput").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
}).focus(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    return false;
});
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/GxsEC/5/

Comment: I will take a look at the source, but I found this related Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9569310/497356. I don't think your question  is the same though.